# Using STI path with same controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I am using STI and am wondering, do I have to have a separate controller for each model?  I have a situation where I only use the create and edit actions for one model in the STI relationship, but I get an 'undefined method' error if I try to do a form for.  More specifically, I have two models that inherit from List:

```
class RegularList < List
class OtherList < List
```

and I have a lists controller that handles these actions, but I only create new models with RegularList using forms.  i.e. the only situation where I use a form_for to create a new List object is with RegularList.  What I would like to do is something like:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController

def new
  @list = RegularList.new
end
```

otherwise the route for creating a new list looks like regular_list/new but I would like it to just be list/new.  Thoughts?

EDIT:  The problem is when I use the above code, I get an 'undefined method' error.  My view looks like this:

...

So it seems that there is some problem with using a RegularList object in the Lists controller and this is the main problem I am trying to address.  Sorry, I realize that was not the clearest explanation.

Comment: Problem description can be better. I gave up trying understand your question after 5 minutes.

Comment: i believe his question is pretty clear.

Comment: Can you include the error details? ( i.e. which method got undefined error?)

Comment: I understand only first part of the question. I really don't know what the problem is about :).

Comment: why can't you just create a `@list = List.new` and set the type when you're saving the record?

Comment: Yea, that's exactly what I did, but the problem arises again with the edit action.  In edit it is finding the RegularList object and throwing the error.  I just used new as an example b/c it was simpler.

Answer (score 15):

I know this is kind of late, but maybe this will be helpful for other people.  You want to use the `becomes` method.  Let's say you are editing `@list` which is an instance of `RegularList`.  Then do

```
form_for @list.becomes(List)
```

Answer (score -4):

> I am using STI and am wondering, do I have to have a separate controller for each model?

No, you don't.